# The difference between metro ethernet vs fiber internet?

Tags: internet, ethernet, fiber

I am confusing these two things each other. Okay, fiber is a type of media used to conduct light signals rather than electric signals conducted across copper cables and thus offering high speed internet in this way.

However, there's something called metropolitan ethernet. Doesn't this also involve fiber cables and offer internet service?

What is the difference?

Comment: If both use fiber cables then there is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

the metropolitan Ethernet is designed for very high speed connections, and is used in high time-sensitive, speed-demanding net-interactions, such as banks transactions, and high profile companies data-transmissions, the speed is measured in MBps (Mega Bytes per second) instead of the wide available, domestic-used 'home' connections wich are measured in Mbps (Mega bits per second, wich is slower)

this connection generally uses Optic Fiber because the speed / cost ratio, and uses microwave signal as fallback connection, so isn't generally avaliable for 'domestic-users', basically that's what you need to know about it

Answer (score 0):

Metro-E, as it is called, is a Layer 2 technology (LAN Ethernet) that utilizes the Service Providers network only to connect sites together. it is basically a metro sized LAN like the LAN in your office.

Internet is a layer 3 connection (TCP/IP) that utilizes the Internet of networks including the Service Providers network you connect to and then the next nearest "peering" point to transfer your traffic to the destination.

Usually Metro-E cost more than Internet; sometimes Dedicated or Managed Internet can be as costly.  Internet and DIA will utilize the Internet for transport of traffic.

Metro-E is usually a private network where the Internet is public and shared.

Pick Internet of Metro-E if you get good speeds and diverse providers.  Do not buy circuits from one SP; either buy separately from two SPs or buy them from a circuit aggregator.